# Passenger forking with Nginx, action cable & redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, passenger, actioncable, phusion

I have some problems on my real time notifier with Passenger (v6.0.0) and Action_cable on my staging server : when i do some action linked to action_cable, some new passenger process appear (forking...) and my memory consumption increase and do not go back down.

My routes config :

```
mount ActionCable.server => '/user_notifs'
```

My Nginx config :

```
location /user_notifs {
        passenger_app_group_name phusion_staging_action_cable;
        passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
}
```

My cable.yml

```
staging:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

On my htop, i have like 30 process like this :

```
Passenger AppPreloader: /xxxxxx/curent (forking...)
```

Can you help me ? Thank's

Comment: ps : It's work great on development :) So it's an Passenger config issue i think

Answer (score 0):

More details with this print of screen (Only one client connected on the web-app) :[image: HTOP Print Screen]